# x509 certificate signed issue in terraform planing

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, aws-cli, terraform-provider-aws, cacerts

terraform throws the following error in logs in debug mode when planing terraform. I use aws cli 2.0 on a windows machine. The error comes up only for aws west region deployment. the east is working fine. I tried updating the certificate chain in the python folder path C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\Lib\site-packages\certifi.
still getting error. no luck

```
2021/06/07 19:30:58 [DEBUG] [aws-sdk-go] DEBUG: Send Request ec2/DescribeAccountAttributes failed, attempt 8/25, error RequestError: send request failed
2021-06-07T19:30:58.801+0530 [DEBUG] plugin.terraform-provider-aws_v2.70.0_x4.exe: caused by: Post https://ec2.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

Answer (score 0):

Terraform providers are written in `go` and it should grab CA certificates from the default OS trust store.

There are a couple of things that can cause given error:

#### 1. AWS CA update

During the last couple of years AWS was migrating to their own Certificate Authority, so this might be related. You can see their announcement blogs [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prepare-for-aws-move-to-its-own-certificate-authority/).

For Windows installing latest OS updates should be enough to pull new CA certs.

You can also check AWS docs on how to install their CAs manually [here](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/messaging-and-targeting/669-2/)

#### 2. Outdated terraform provider

From provided logs looks like you are using `aws` provider version `2.70.0`. It was build with older version of `go` that since had some fixes related to certificate validation on Windows. Try updating your provider to [latest version](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest)